# Angularjs Protractor E2E test 'App Already Bootstrapped with this Element'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am running into an issue where my Protractor tests always fail with the error message:

```
UnknownError: Error Message => '[ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '<html lang="en" data-ng-app="pmApp" class="js draganddrop no-video no-audio ng-scope">'
```

The current Angularjs docs suggest the issue is when the application is being manually bootstrapped, whereas in my case, this is not the case, we are just using:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="pmApp">
```

The normal site works fine, without an error or warning, but as soon as I set up my tests using Protractor the error occurs. To note, the test was passing when I was using angularjs 1.08, but has since failed when using 1.25

The test is like so:

```
describe('Campaigns page', function() {
var ptor;

beforeEach(function() {
    // Sets the width of the window, otherwise the default min width
    // of our site is to small and the login page un-usable
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1200, 800);
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();

    browser.driver.get(ptor.baseUrl + '/login');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('user_email')).sendKeys('admin@aperture.*************.com');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('user_password')).sendKeys('*************');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.button.primary')).click();

    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return (/\/#\/$/.test(url));
        });
    });

    // Now ensure the angular app is loaded and it knows about it
    browser.get('#/');
});

it('Should list campaigns on the page', function() {
    browser.get('#/campaigns');

    browser.findElements(by.css('.main-campaign')).then(function(results) {
        expect(results.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

});
```

});

*note actual login details removed for safety.

As soon as the:
    browser.get('#/campaigns');

is called, the error happens.

I have also tried using the login functionality as an onPrepare in the protractor conf file, but the same thing happens.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Full stack trace:

```
Stacktrace:
 UnknownError: Error Message => '[ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '<html lang="en" data-ng-app="pmApp" class="js draganddrop no-video no-audio ng-scope">'
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/ng/btstrpd?p0=%3Chtml%20lang%3D%22en%22%20data-ng-app%3D%22pmApp%22%20class%3D%22js%20draganddrop%20no-video%20no-audio%20ng-scope%22%3E'
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"159","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:29064"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"args\":[[]],\"script\":\"return (function () {\n    // Continue to bootstrap Angular.\n    angular.resumeBootstrap(arguments[0]);\n  }).apply(null, arguments);\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/64b440e0-68b9-11e3-b92a-e1efe36914bc/execute"}
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'peters-mbp', ip: '192.168.0.3', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9', java.version: '1.6.0_65'

Answer (score 0):

I have come across similar situation yesterday and was able to resolve this by adding a browser.ignoresynchronisation = true before each test. This happens if you bootstrap your  Angular app manually using resumeBootstrap. I also needed to make the browser to sleep for some time to have the actual results come through.

Hope this helps